# MongoDB no Azure

Tags: c#, mongodb

Há um tempo atrás eu tive uma surpresa desagradável em minha fatura no azure por conta de um banco de dados MongoDB que eu possuía para acesso de uma aplicação.

Criei, por exemplo, os documentos:

- Cliente
- Produto
- Pedido

Fiz toda a programação de forma relacional (obviamente contra os padrões no-sql, mas...) no fim das contas a azure me deu uma conta absurda para pagar pois considerava cada documento criado como se fosse uma base de dados. Assim, cobrava por uso individual dos documentos.

Contornei essa situação, utilizando apenas um documento para armazenar clientes produtos e pedidos. Claro que cada um com um campo "type" especificando o que era, para poder obtê-lo posteriormente.

Minha dúvida: Não consigo acreditar que isto está correto, porém, não penso em outra forma para resolver.
Hoje eu já descontinuei a aplicação, então isso é simplesmente uma dúvida mesmo.

Qual a melhor forma para se modelar estes tipos no mongodb nesta situação?
Cria-se realmente um documento para cada tipo de objeto?
Cria-se um atributo especificando o tipo do objeto para posterior utilização?

Alguém pode dar uma luz?

Obs.: Minha aplicação foi desenvolvida com c#.

Comment: Eu uso o mongodb atlas, la dentro você consegue um plano gratuito para o banco, porém essa opção só está disponível para o AWS.

Comment: Entendo. Mas na realidade, esta não é a questão. É mais um caso de modelagem e experiência também

Comment: Infelizmente, não tenho mais os fontes. Mas posso dar um exemplo aqui, onde teria uma tabela produtos, uma clientes e uma orçamentos. Pelo que entendo deveria modelar um documento para cada correto? Se não, neste contexto do AZURE, como faríamos?

Comment: Isso é um absurdo, banco de dados é uma coisa, documento é outra.No mundo relacional o documento seria a linha de uma tabela, então não há motivos para você ser cobrado como cada documento representar um banco de dados. A não ser que a Azure esteja te cobrando pelo n° requisições e não pelo banco em si. Neste caso, poderia então ter uma conta alta se tem muitas requisições.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caso Cliente, Produto e Pedido não são documentos, muito menos bancos de dados eles são coleções, a forma a qual está fazendo está certa (Caso realmente estiver os criando como coleções) o único problema na sua modelagem é seguir a estrutura relacional que na verdade só deixa o MongoDB lento...

Houve realmente um problema na sua fatura e eles não deveriam ter te cobrado por diversas bases já que provavelmente você tinha 1 base e 3 coleções.
Caso houver dúvidas de criação e você ainda tiver o Script de criação das bases utilize os comandos a seguir para confirmar o que eu disse:

```
show dbs //Mostra todas bases
show collections // Mostra as coleções
```

**Importante**: o MongoDB ao ser instalado já cria 2 bancos de dados chamados Admin e Local, você podia estar pagando por eles em adição ao seu.